# How to create the equivalent of WolframAlpha symbolic solution to equation in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, wolframalpha

I have found WolframAlpha very useful in generating a solution range for each of my variables for the equation:

```
200a + 1400b + 100c = 100000
```

where

```
0 <= a < 50
50 <= b < 150
150 <= c < 300
```

What I am after is something like the results in the 2nd line of the 'Solutions' box [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200*a%2B1400*b%2B100*c+%3D+100000%2C+0%3C%3Da%3C50%2C+50%3C%3Db%3C150%2C+150%3C%3Dc%3C300):

[image: WolframAlpha screenshot]

How can I reproduce this in Python without the use of WolframAlpha? I am thinking perhaps using Sympy, but I am not familiar with this (I made a start below, but don't think it is on the right track). Any advice would be appreciated.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
c = Symbol('c')
solve([a >= 0, a < 50, b >= 50, b < 150, c >= 150, c < 300, 100*a + 1400*b + 100*c - 100000], a)
```

Comment: This is called [tag:symbolic-math]. Also, you shouldn't hotlink to WolframAlpha, it will cause them unnecessary hits; best to post an image here.